# Customizing arrows with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm working with Tikz package and I want to create a new arrow tip. So I used the following code which I found in internet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

% Code for the new arrow tip, called halfcirc.
\pgfarrowsdeclare{halfcirc}{halfcirc}
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfarrowsleftextend{-4\arrowsize-.5\pgflinewidth}
\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin % fix join
\pgfsetroundcap % fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-4\arrowsize}{4\arrowsize}}
\pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{4\arrowsize}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}

% Declare a reversed version called revhalfcirc.
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{revhalfcirc}{revhalfcirc}{halfcirc}{halfcirc}

% Demonstration of the arrow tip.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-3,-2) grid (3,2);
\draw[line width=10pt, revhalfcirc-halfcirc] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But an error pops up:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@arrow@right@revhalfcirc -> \arrowsize 
                                           =0.2pt \advance \arrowsize by .5\...
l.32 ...pt, revhalfcirc-halfcirc] (-2,0) -- (0,0);

?
```

What is the problem? I am a beginner in using Tikz.

Comment: Nice! But I though that this arrow was on the predefined ones.

Answer (score 6):

You need to load the `tikz` library providing support for arrows and such, by adding

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

just below your call to the `tikz` package. This library then provides the `\arrowsize` command and others.

In your example, the code should look like :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

% Code for the new arrow tip, called halfcirc.
\pgfarrowsdeclare{halfcirc}{halfcirc}
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfarrowsleftextend{-4\arrowsize-.5\pgflinewidth}
\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
\arrowsize=0.2pt
\advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundjoin % fix join
\pgfsetroundcap % fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-4\arrowsize}{4\arrowsize}}
\pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{4\arrowsize}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}

% Declare a reversed version called revhalfcirc.
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{revhalfcirc}{revhalfcirc}{halfcirc}{halfcirc}

% Demonstration of the arrow tip.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-3,-2) grid (3,2);
\draw[line width=10pt, revhalfcirc-halfcirc] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiled, it gives the following output, which seems to be what you expect :
[image: Output]

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. I still get the same error:

! Undefined control sequence.\pgf@arrow@right@revhalfcirc -> \arrowsize 
                                           =0.2pt \advance \arrowsize by .5\...
l.32 ...pt, revhalfcirc-halfcirc] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
                                                  
? 

I don't get why..

Comment: That's strange, I tried it before posting and it worked like a charm. Could you update your MWE so that we can see what's going on?

Comment: Sure I am trying to write it in code format

Comment: You can always edit your first question to add such precisions.

Comment: I can t manage to copy it, but it is exactly the same as I wrote above, but adding 
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
just below \usepackage{tikz}

Comment: I don't know what to say. I posted my full code above, maybe you can try copy/pasting it to see if it compiles. Also, make sure you don't forget to save before compiling, that's an easy mistake.

Comment: I really don't know, maybe the package I installed is corrupted or something. I saved before compiling but still get the same error. Anyway, thank you very much!