# Customizing arrow tips with tikz in order to to mimic arrows of engineering drawings

Tags: tikz-arrows

I need to mimic in Tikz the arrow tip created by most CAD packages for engineering drawings. The targeted arrow tip is an elongated sharp triangle, with an angle of about 17 degrees. The desired shape would be approximately the equivalent of "triangle 17" as shown  in the arrow library (link below), but the length of the tip is also about three times the width (the short side of the triangle).

[List of available TikZ libraries with a short introduction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/list-of-available-tikz-libraries-with-a-short-introduction)

I have found below an example of a customized arrow tip, but do not have the skills to convert the code in a way solving my problem.

[Customizing arrows with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73878/customizing-arrows-with-tikz)

Comment: I guess tikz's stealth arrows, while an improvement, are still not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52786/din-conform-arrowheads-and-hatching-in-tikz look at the accepted answer arrow heads.

Comment: Can you show an image of the type of arrow that you want? Your link gives a list of google results rather than a specific document

Comment: @Aditya I have edited my qustion to delete the link that did not work, as it implied a re-direction.The document showing examples of engineerng arrows  can be found by googling "technical drawing specification resource" The arrows (red) are seen on page 16.

Comment: @Yves, all we need to know is that you need a 3mm-long by 1mm-wide arrow head, according to the picture in the [reference](http://www.vcaa.vic.edu.au/Documents/vce/visualcomm/technical_drawing_specifications.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is a 3mm x 1mm arrow head:
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{AS arrow}{AS arrow}
{
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-0.5\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfutil@tempdima=3mm%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by -0.5\pgflinewidth%   
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=3mm%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by -3.54138\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
    \pgfsetmiterjoin
    \pgftransformxshift{\pgfutil@tempdima}
    \pgfutil@tempdima=1.01379\pgfutil@tempdima%       
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpointpolar{170.53768}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{-170.53768}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines, step=1mm] (0,-0.5) grid (1,0.5);
\draw[-AS arrow]                 (0,0.2)  -- (1,0.2);
\draw[-AS arrow, fill opacity=0] (0,-0.2) -- (1,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```