# label overlapping with arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

First, the working code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={,fill=white!20,draw,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (dancing) {dancing};
  \node[main node] (monkey) [below of=dancing] {monkey};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (dancing) edge node [below] {test} (monkey)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As shown below, I get overlapping text with the arrow.
[image: dancing monkey]

Is there a way to change this? Can I also modify the size of the arrow for individual arrows in my graph?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It's good that oyu have posted all of the code, however, it's better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  that people can immediately compile to see what the issues are. This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. I just added working code. Is this better for you?

Comment: Now I am morally obliged to look at this:) More importantly, it is much easier for any one to play with your code so you are likely to get help more quickly. If you change `node [below] {test}` to `node [right] {test}` then the label is printed to the right of the arrow. See [customizing-arrows-with-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73878/customizing-arrows-with-tikz), for example, on how to customise the arrows

Comment: @Andrew thanks for looking into it. I am familiar with basic customization. I am just trying to figure out why the text is overlapping with the arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution. use `rotatebox` from `graphicx` package, or with the help from tikzlibrary `postioning` with `above left=xxcm and xxcm` or `below right=xx cm and xxcm`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={,fill=white!20,draw,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (dancing) {dancing};
  \node[main node,below=3cm of dancing] (monkey) {monkey};

\path[]
    (dancing) edge node [] {\rotatebox[origin=cc]{90}{test}} (monkey)
;
\path[]
    (dancing) edge node [below right=0.5cm and 0.1cm] {test} (monkey)
;
\path[]
    (dancing) edge node [above left=0.5cm and 0.1cm] {test} (monkey)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: HI @Jesse. Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to make them all rotate 90 degrees?

Comment: @kolonel Yes, simply copy the `\rotate[]{}{test}` to wrap the remaining text as the first one did. `[above left or below right]` are to set the locations while  `rotate` is to rotate the content.